# Need to Bulletproof this PHP include. Getting Failed to Open Stream

Tags: php

I've got some functions in my file that require taxonomy.php to execute. I'm attempting to include the file like so...(this is called from functions.php, which is located in wp_content/themes/mytheme/

```
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .'/wp-admin/includes/taxonomy.php');
```

However, depending on the particular server setup, its hit or miss (mostly hit) whether the include will be found. In the case its not found, I get this error...

Warning: include(/home/user/domainname.com/wp-admin/includes/taxonomy.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/user/domainname.com/testing123/wp-content/themes/mytheme/functions.php on line 10

***UPDATE: Assuming I'm already doing about as much as I can by using DOCUMENT_ROOT, is there a means of avoiding the error that occurs when the file is not found? And I will be checking for function_exists in any functions that require taxonomy.php so as to suppress errors...***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the only way to bulletproof this is to actually configure it on each server you deploy it on. If you can't assume `document_root` is a reliable factor, I can't imagine any other variable that could give you a better result.

You could start searching for `taxonomy.php` but that is expensive, and horribly prone to failure or picking the wrong file (what happens if my neighbor has wordpress installed in `/home/user/domainname2.com`?

Comment: Thanks Pekka, I do believe that the current approach of document_root is best as well. I just need a means of suppressing the "failed to open stream" error if the file is not found.

Comment: Ahh ok. You would have to check whether the file exists, using `file_exists()`.

Comment: Thanks Pekka, I appreciate the help. I'll use file_exists in conjunction with function_exists to control error supression.

Answer (score 0):

If your application **depends** on a particular file, you should be using [require](https://www.php.net/require)/[require_once](https://www.php.net/require_once) to ensure your application does not partially load despite missing the required file.

As for making sure that file always exists and is in a place you need it, you could move that to a configuration file and allow the user running the software to set it, along with auto-attempting to find the find in the event the user is clueless.

Comment: Hi Nick, the app has 2 functions that require taxonomy.php and they are not critical to the operation. I'm just auto creating a couple of categories in the event they don't already exist. The user can manually create the directories otherwise and their existence is not required.

So, I suppose I just need error supression if the include file is not found and I can't seem to figure out how to suppress the "failed to open stream" error.

Comment: You can obviously do that with an `@` although I am ashamed of posting that here ;) Bad practice. Instead, you should probably use `file_exists()` first...